# How to bind action to ctrl-f1 in screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, console, terminfo

I know I can do:

```
bindkey "...." action
```

where .... is what i get by typing ctrl-v and then ctrl-f1. but it looks bad, contains bad characters (^[), and is generally not cool.

when binding to f1, i can do:

```
bindkey -k k1 action
```

but I can't seem to find termcap capability name for ctrl-functionkey.

Where can I find it?

When I press ctrl-v ctrl-f1 on terminal I get:

```
^[O5P
```

these are 4 bytes, not 5:

```
=$ echo "^[O5P" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 4f 35 50 0a                                    |.O5P.|
```

Comment: What do you get when you press `ctrl-v f1` and `ctrl-v ctrl-f1` (since this depends on what terminal emulator you're using)? What does `echo $TERM` give you?

Comment: ^[O5P : =$ echo "^[O5P" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 4f 35 50 0a                                    |.O5P.|

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `screen` apparently doesn't understand enough function keys to be able to process Ctrl-F1. At least I have not been able to get `bindkey -k FF stuff "pressed Ctrl-F1"` to work even after trying to define FF or kf25 using the `termcap` or `terminfo` commands in `~/.screenrc`. I also tried "kf25" in the `bindkey` command. In either case, I get a "bindkey: unknown key" message.

Perhaps you or someone else will be able to get farther using the information here.

Otherwise, you can continue to use the ugly, uncool method. For onlookers, it's uncool to use hard-coded escape sequences instead of capability names because it won't be portable to other terminal types.

Capability names:

```
                    termcap        terminfo        xterm

F1                     k1            kf1           ^[OP

Shift-F1               F3            kf13          ^[O2P

Ctrl-F1                FF            kf25          ^[O5P

Ctrl-Shift-F1          FR            kf37          ^[O6P
```

Output from `tput`:

```
$ tput -Txterm kf25 | hd
00000000  1b 4f 35 50                                       |.O5P|
```

Comment: it doesn't fully work, but - how did you found the capability names? is there some command to list them?

Comment: It's not obvious how the capability names map to shifted and ctrl'd keys, it's just some old knowledge rolling around in my memory. However the capability names are documented in `man 5 terminfo` and `man 5 termcap`. Some might find this list of function keys for all terminfo entries interesting (output is *very* long): `for i in $(find /lib/terminfo/ -type f -printf "%f\n"); do echo; echo $i; for j in {0..63}; do echo  "kf$j $(tput -T$i kf$j|hexdump -e '""  8/1 "'\''%_c'\'' " "\n"')"; done; done|less`

Comment: "not obvious" - other than kf1 + 12 = kf13 ( + 12 = kf25 ) ( + 12 = kf37 ) where PC keyboards typically have 12 function keys.